# Why can't my bitcoin-qt sync with network?

Tags: client, bitcoin-core

For the last 32 hours my bitcoin-qt has been unable to sync with the network even with my firewall and VPN switched off. Any ideas what else to check? Using Windows 7 SP1 x64 and have rebooted the machine. Internet connection is fine, plenty of space for the blockchain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the debug window. Does it show peers? In addition, look at the debug.log file, it might show specific problem information.

Comment: No it doesn't show up any peers. In fact when I connect it to my mobile hotspot it works fine but when I try to connect it using my college internet connection, it is not able to connect to the peers. Please clarify.

Comment: It's possible that your college network blocks bitcoin access by policy, you should maybe ask the administrator there. And please note that this site is not a discussion forum, you should maybe ask a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact I described my issue very clearly in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52906/unable-to-connect-to-peers-nor-synchronize-the-network . Hope you can help me more by analyzing the logs over there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the case with you, however in the previous version of QT I got the same problem, it couldn't synchronize even when I left it on for 3 whole days, what I did then was create a new wallet on another PC, transfer my balance there, uninstall the problematic wallet, create a new one and then transfer my balance back there. It then took it only a couple of hours to synchronize. Don't forget to update your receiving addresses in miming pools, exchanges, etc after you complete this process.

Answer (score -1):

Bitcoin Wallet is installing block chain from Bitcoin Network. This takes time , you should wait for it. If it takes long time than follow these steps -

1. Update your wallet
2. just transfer your balance to newly installed bitcoin wallet. and delete this one.For new wallet you should install block chain from bitcoin network.
   Check your internet connection also

Comment: Use extreme caution if deleting an old wallet.  If you don't move your coin first, you may lose access to it permanently.

Answer (score -2):

you need to just wait, its 6GB of data and can take anywhere from several minutes to several hours, there have even been reports of it taking days.  Its because of the size of the hard drive, the speed of the computer, the speed of the internet connection etc.

Cheers

Comment: 6GB in the last 32 hours? No